# "Звездочки" в input

Tags: html, css

Как сделать чтобы были звездочки в `<input type="password">`, а не шарики и квадраты?
Возможно ли это сделать?

Comment: Звездочки и шарики и квадраты XD) зависят от браузера и его версии! И эти звездочки и шарики никак не влияют на качество передаваемых данных!

Comment: Тут дело не в передаче данных,а со стороны верстки ,хотел что бы были вот такие ***** вместо шариков итд )
В вопросе кстати не было ничего сказано про передачу данных xD

Comment: Можете попробовать поиграться со шрифтами, но никакой гарантии это не даст.

Comment: @ling, Он добъется изменения шариков на квадратики... И все. =) На звездочки не заменить так: это действительно другой символ, причем чуть ли не на уровне ОС в некоторых случаях.

Comment: Мне всегда казалось что это на уровне HTML,неужели надо будет JavaScript подключать  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
.replacer{border:1px #666 dotted;height:20px;display:inline-block;color:#444;background:#eee}
.replacer.current{border-color:#ccc;color:#000;background:#fff}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yandex.st/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

*: <input type="password" rel="to-replace" /><br />
$: <input type="password" rel="to-replace-$" /><br />
.: <input type="password" rel="to-replace-." value="1234" /><br />

<script type="text/javascript">
$('input:password[rel^="to-replace"]').each(function(){
    var s = this.getAttribute('rel').replace('to-replace', '');
    if(!s) s = '*';
    else s = s.replace('-', '');

    var t = $(this);
    var r = $('<span class="replacer"></span>').css({
        height: t.height(),
        width: t.width(),
        display: 'inline-block'
    });

    t.css({position:'absolute',left:'-5000px'})
    .keyup(function(){
        var str = '';
        for(var i = 0; i < this.value.length; ++i)
            str += s;
        $(this).next().html(str);
    })
    .focusin(function(){
        $(this).next().addClass('current');
    })
    .focusout(function(){
        $(this).next().removeClass('current');
    })
    .after(r);

    t.keyup();
});
$('.replacer').live('click', function(){
    var t = $(this).prev()[0];
    t.focus();
    t.value = t.value;
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Немного кривоватое решение, но его можно доработать. Напильником. =)

Answer (score 1):

`<input type="text">`  и обработка поля JavaScript-ом?

Comment: Идея верная ;)

Answer (score 1):

посмотри [вот этот пример](http://jsfiddle.net/jamwaffles/SzuD4/) - замена "шариков" на картинку. Можно нарисовать звездочку и подменять уже на звездочку

Comment: Курсор оказывается среди шариков в некоторых браузерах. Это напрягает.

Comment: Шарики не исчезают при удалении текста. Да, и они шире знака замены, поэтому курсор за ними "не успевает". Google Chrome

Comment: А если заменять не на картинки,а на символ, например, "*" ? тоже будут подобные глюки?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id='fakePassword' />
```

//JS:

```
var fakePassword = new Object();
fakePassword.element = getElementById('fakePassword');
fakePassword.element.onkeyup = function(){
  fakePassword.value = fakePassword.element.value;
  fakePassword.element.value.replace(/[^*]/,'*');
}
//...
yourForm.onsumbit = function(){
  fakePassword.element.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  fakePassword.element.value = fakePassword.value;
}
```

Рассматривайте как псевдокод: работоспособность не проверял, но мысль эта.
При вводе текста, все символы, кроме звездочки, заменяются на звездочку, а перед этим, значение сохраняется в переменную.
Непосредственно перед отправкой формы, полю позвращается его значение.

P.S. если отвечать прямо: нет, в type="password" нельзя сделать кроссбраузерное решение для замены шариков на звездочки возможностями верстки. Некоторые браузеры понимают mask аттрибут, но отнюдь не все.